# Why does std::allocator require propagate_on_container_move_assignment to be true?

Tags: c++, c++11, allocator

According to current Standard (20.7.9), `std::allocator` has a member `propagate_on_container_move_assignment` which is set to `true_type`:

> template  class allocator
>   {
>     public:
>       typedef size_t size_type;
>       typedef ptrdiff_t difference_type;
>       typedef T* pointer;
>       typedef const T* const_pointer;
>       typedef T& reference;
>       typedef const T& const_reference;
>       typedef T value_type;
>       template  struct rebind { typedef allocator other; };
>       **typedef true_type propagate_on_container_move_assignment;**
>       **typedef true_type is_always_equal;**
>       [...]

`std::allocator` has no data members and always compared as equal with any other `std::allocator`. Is there any reason to move those default allocators on move assignment?

Comment: This isn't C++11. `is_always_equal` was added post-C++14.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm answering relative to C++11, as you indicated in the tag:

If the trait weren't true, then assignment operations would need to perform a *runtime check* on whether the allocators are equal. Yes, of course the allocators would always be equal, but the code doesn't know that and would still have to perform the check, and thus you cannot offer a noexcept guarantee. With POCMA = true, you can statically know that you will steal resources and thus won't throw.

C++14 made the `std::allocator` have POCMA = true (in [LWG2103](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-defects.html#2103)). It was false in C++11.

C++17 introduced the new trait `is_always_equal` (in [N4258](http://wg21.link/n4258)) to allow a non-throwing exception specification for operations even when POCMA is false.

(I think it's fair to say that the design of allocators has never quite been completed, and to this day nobody is entirely sure how they are supposed to work.)

Comment: The reason it was made POCMA is that it affects the requirements on the container elements, not just the exception specification. Without POCMA (or `is_always_equal`) you have to allow for the possibility of element-wise move.

Comment: I have a corollary question:  why not defining a constexpr operator==? why this pocma necessary. I would imagine that if I were using such an operator as the condition of an if statement, dead code elimination would produce the same code as if I were using tag dispatch with POCMA no?

Comment: @Oliv A constexpr `operator==` would be possible, and is discussed in [lwg 2108](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-defects.html#2108). To use that you'd need to try the equality comparison in a SFINAE context to see if it's a valid constant expression (because not all allocators would have a constexpr `operator==`). Tag dispatching is simpler. Dead code elimination still works for a non-constexpr `operator==` that always returns true. In practice it doesn't make much difference.

Comment: @JonathanWakely Thank you for the answer. I'd like to share some peace of experiment. I am getting used to program with concept TS since a while and using it, I discovered that most of my design decision where motivated by the difficulty I had to use and maintain code using SFINAE. It seems to be the case in the STL. I have read the standard N4618: "is_always_equal:true_type only if the expression
a1 == a2 is guaranteed to be
true for any two...". This is an unnecessary constraint propagation to a programmer of an allocator. This requirement can be hard coded. Why not hard coding it?

Comment: @Oliv I don't understand the question (defining `using is_always_equal = true_type;` for an allocator _does_ hardcode it), but I don't think it belongs in a comment here. StackOverflow comments are not for discussion. Stick to the topic of this answer. Ask a new question if you have questions.

Comment: @JonathanWakely I was thinking compiler intrinsic to retrieve information compiler actually knows, but this may be more complex than I initialy thougt. Most of the time traits are code duplication (information duplication). When a programmer declares a `constexpr operator==` that always return true, the compiler get the information that `is_always_equal` is intended to provides once more. This is code duplication. I do not think C++ needs more and more rules. It need code introspection abilities. concept TS drastically improves the code, but even more introspection would be better.